# SwiftUI - NavigationLink inside of NavigationLink Bug

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationlink

im trying to create a NavigationLink List inside of my NavigationLink as a DetailView.
Sadly im getting weird UI Bugs. Here is the Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("label", destination: DetailView())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("label", destination: Text("detail"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Error Message:

```
2020-01-20 00:30:04.302351+0100 Test[14029:1128128] [Assert] UIScrollView does not support multiple observers implementing
_observeScrollView:willEndDraggingWithVelocity:targetContentOffset:unclampedOriginalTarget:.
Scroll view <_TtC7SwiftUIP33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A4925UpdateCoalescingTableView:
0x7fbdc3865c00; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES;
autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002fb4f30>;
layer = <CALayer: 0x6000021592c0>; contentOffset: {0, -212}; contentSize: {375, 44.5}; adjustedContentInset: {212, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource:
<_TtGC7SwiftUIP10$10c5cea4419ListCoreCoordinatorGVS_20SystemListDataSourceOs5Never_GOS_19SelectionManagerBoxS2___:
0x7fbdc25a4470>>, new observer <UINavigationController:
0x7fbdc3875a00>, removing old observer <UINavigationController: 0x7fbdc3840c00>
```

Here is the UI Bug:

[image: Image UI Bug]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need another `NavigationView` in the `DetailView` - it's already into the `NavigationView` of the `ContentView`. You may read [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5824937-swiftui-tutorial-navigation), there this question is answered. And you code should looks like:

```swift
struct NavigationLinks: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("label", destination: DetailViewWithNavLink())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailViewWithNavLink : View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink("label", destination: Text("detail")
                .navigationBarTitle("Text from item in Detail View List", displayMode: .inline))
        }
    .navigationBarTitle("Detail view")
    }
}
```

and you'll see:

[image]

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer! I have now a different problem.

Comment: Im trying to bind two bools for each NavigationLink isActive item. But Im getting again UI Bugs and the App crashes.

Comment: @Max , sorry, hard to understand what bugs do you have without code snippets or errors. Please, add them somewhere or try to ask another question. I don't know is there any kind of chat on stack overflow

Comment: Ok I will do another question. Thanks for you help!